# Implementation for Bresenham's ellipse drawing algorithm in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, bresenham

I'm looking for one to build a MS-paint like app.

Comment: is that a homework? in which institution do you read?

Comment: It is homework. I tagged it as such cause it is. I'm allowed to use implementations now written by me as long as I acknowledge the source, the program isn't an ellipse drawer, it's a full ms-paint knockoff in opengl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the [pseudocode here](http://homepage.smc.edu/kennedy_john/belipse.pdf). Worked pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is for making 3D applications. Using it for pixel-based things like a paint program will make things very hard.

The closest thing I can imagine is to paint the pixels for the ellipse to texture surface and then show it as sprite. Be sure that you always have identity transform set, otherwise the result may look blurry.

A good alternative for OpenGl in your case would be SDL. It is simpler and pixel based.

Comment: I'll look into this out of curiosity. Still, the homework demands an opengl implementation.

Comment: Maybe you could consider doing another type of project if openGL is demanded.

Comment: The homework is a MS-paint like application in openGL.

Comment: the GL in OpenGL stands for "graphics library", not for "3d only". you can easily draw stuff with OpenGL by using glVertex2() ...

Answer (score 1):

Bresenham's drawing algorithm is used to scan convert the ellipse, i.e. correctly draw and fill the edges of it.  OpenGL is a polygon based graphics library that does it's own scan conversion, so I'd say you are thinking of doing it the wrong way.

Personally I'd calculate some points round the edge of the polygon, e.g. by regularly stepping from 0 to 360 degrees and then draw a GL_FAN with the center as the first point and the calculated points as the rest (and including the 0 degree point again at the end).

This will not be perfectly accurate, but good and fast for most purposes.

You could be more sophisticated and generate more edge points if the ellipse is larger, which will improve the accuracy.

Comment: Nah, I've been asked to supply an implementation of bresenham's midpoint algorithm in opengl for the ellipse explicitly.